# Cubic Transformations - Graph shown is best represented by the equation:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

[image]

The answer is out of B or D:

$f(x) = -(x-a)^3 + b$ because turning point at $(0,0)$ is now $(a,b)$

OR

$f(x+a)^3$ because "$a$" is implied as negative...  $(0,0)$ is now $(-a,b)$

The textbook answer is D, but my teachers argue B

Comment: It can't be $D$ 'cause $-(a+a)^3+b = b-8a^3 = b$ iff $a=0$. From the graph, it's clear that $a \neq 0$. Your teacher's right.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the way the picture is drawn and the options give, teacher is correct. What is usually seen in graph transformation problems is actual numbers. So if the turning point had been written out as $(-3,5)$, then the resulting function would have been $f(x) = -(x-(-3))^3+5 = -(x+3)^3+5$.

Comment: it cant be..."a" is shifted to the left. therefore it is (x+a)

that's how you would do any question....

Comment: Technically all shift are done in the form $(x-a)$. It is just when the number is negative, we rewrite it using $+$ like in my example with actual numbers. Because the picture is labeled $(a,b)$, that tells us to just use the letter $a$ as is and not worry about its sign. genepeer mentioned this in his comment to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Take the function $y=x^3$.Transformations:-
1) The graph is inverted.So equation is $y=-x^3$
2)Shift the graph to the left by $a$ units.So equation is $y=-(x-a)^3$
3)Shift the graph up by $b$ units.So equation is $y-b=-(x-a)^3 \implies y=-(x-a)^3+b$ which is option B

Comment: when you shit the graph to the left it should be f(x+a)
(x-a) shifts the graph to the right.